# Regex for specific string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

The string should look like this

```
"1-7;IN;dd"
(For example, 2;IN;43).
```

First value before semicolon should be digit 1 to 7. And last value after second semicolon should be 01 to 99 number.

My suggestion

```
@"/^\d[1-7];IN;\d{1,2}$/"
```

does not work properly

Comment: Paste your regex in a regex tester. `\d[1-7]` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @CodeCaster I didn't vote, but it seems like a reasonable question to me.  There was effort.  Meh, maybe lack of research I guess.

Comment: Some languages use forward slashes to delineate a regex expression. Generally, you should be using forward slashes or quotations marks, but not both.

Comment: @CodeCaster thank you for offering to use regex tester. Never heard about such a useful thing before

Comment: Use `@"^[1-7];IN;(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you

Comment: Wiktor was almost there. however, his suggestion will also accept `1;IN;999`. The correct regular expression is this: `@"^[1-7];IN;((0[1-9])|([1-9]\d)){1}$"`

Comment: You've rather dramatically changed the question by adding the requirement that the range be `01` to `99` rather than `1` to `99`. In the future, please check your assumptions and be precise in what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your should change your pattern.

1) `/` at the begin and end are not needed

2) `\d[1-7]` is equivalent to `[0-9][1-7]`, but you need only one digit from `1` to `7`

3) `\d{1,2}` matches for one or two digits - in your case you need two digits (from `01` to `99` you should exclude `00`).

Use this pattern for regular expression:

```
^[1-7];IN;(?!00)[0-9]{2}$
```

Comment: `[0-9]{2}` will also match `00`.

Comment: `(?!00)` means "Don't match if the next two characters are `00`"

Answer (score 0):

```
@"^[1-7];IN;[1-9]\d?$"
```

This version ensures the last part is greater than 0 and avoids leading zeros.

Comment: You've correctly identified the pattern needed to match the OP's desired input. Now you should take it a step further and explain where the OP was going wrong, especially why `\d[1-7]` and `/` were wrong choices. This will add a lot more value... "teach a person to fish", etc.

Comment: This will not accept strings like `2;IN;03`, but the OP stated that they should be valid...

Comment: @ZoharPeled The OP changed the question after this answer was posted.

Comment: @JDB I only saw the edited version of the question, so I didn't know that. Anyway, I only commented on the answer, not voted on it, so no harm was done.